# How to add min to current date/specific date and compare both dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Session contain time(min).Either positive or Negative.I want to add that time in current date.If positive,it should get added.If negative,it should get reduced from that.I want to do it from javascript.

```
1 :
         var Time = '<%=Session["Time"]%>';
         var d1 = new Date(),
         d2 = new Date(d1);
         d2.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + Time);
         alert(d2);
```

When I am writing like this (above code) I am getting invalid date.

```
var Time = '<%=Session["Time"]%>';
         var d1 = new Date(),
         d2 = new Date(d1);
         d2.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + 30);
         alert(d2);
```

When I am writing like this (above code) I am getting proper date.Is it a right way to add min to current date.

2 : I am selecting date from date picker,that gives me date like this '03/30/2016',I have another dropdownlist for selecting hours and min.
I want to add hours and time in selected date.Hours is in 24.Time in 60.

```
var d = new Date('03/30/2016');
        d.setHours(d.getHours() + 17);
        d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 54);
        alert(d);
```

Is it a right way to do?

3 : I want compare both date d and d2. d should be greater than d2.If not,should show message to user.

Comment: Output is 30 of <%=Session["Time"]%>

Comment: `var Time = '<%=Session["Time"]%>';` will set `Time` as `'30'` hence it will get concatenated not `added`...Guess...

Comment: then you don't need those single quotes, but that's not the problem...

Comment: what do you mean with _"I am getting invalid date"_ ? because it works fine for me

Comment: Hello guys,if I replace above code with var Time = <%=Session["Time"]%>,I am proper date.Here I removed single quote.Then it worked for me.How I forgot to see that?Thanks all of u for ur help.

Comment: @gurvinder372,it give me date which is 3 Apr.

Comment: Second part is right or wrong?  If I removed single quote from this session variable,it work.But It shows Syntax error at var d1.I can't append semicolon at end. var Time = <%=Session["Time"]%>
         var d1 = new Date(),
         d2 = new Date(d1);
         d2.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + Time);
         alert(d2);

Comment: `I can't append semicolon at end` why not? `var Time = <%=Session["Time"]%>;`

Comment: It shows me syntax error.

Comment: @JuiTest on which line?

Comment: Same line.var Time = <%=Session["Time"]%>;

Comment: If I use like this,it work without any syntax error.var Time = parseInt( '<%=Session["Time"]%>');

Comment: @JuiTest can you confirm if your code is working now?

Comment: @gurvinder372,yes It worked for me.

Comment: I want to compare 2 date that I am showing in alert box.First one like this: Wed Mar 30 2016 11:48:43 GMT+0530(India standard Time)
second one like this : 
Tue Mar 29 2016 17:54:00 GMT+530(India standard Time).I am comparing like this.  if (d2 > d)
            {
                alert('Scheduled date should be greater than current datetime');
            }

Answer (score 0):

> I want compare both date d and d2. d should be greater than d2.If
>   not,should show message to user.

you can compare their millisecond value

```
if (d.getTime() > d2.getTime())
{
  //d is greater than d2
}
```